# Deriving the power formula of the one-sample proportion test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, statistical-power, z-test

I have to derive the power of the z-test in testing
$$
H_0: \pi=\pi_0 \text{ versus } H_1: \pi>\pi_0
$$
Denoting by $p$ the sample proportion, the power equals
$$
Pr\left[\frac{p-\pi_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}} < - 1.96 \mid \text{true} = \pi \right]
$$
$$
= Pr\left[\frac{p-\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}} + \frac{\pi - \pi_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}} < - 1.96 \mid \text{true} = \pi \right]
$$
$$
=\Phi \left(- 1.96 - \frac{\pi - \pi_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}}  \right)
$$
The last equality follows form the fact that $\frac{p-\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}}$ follows asymptotically a $N(0, 1)$ distribution if the true proportion equals $\pi$.

My problem is that the formula still contains $p$ ($\pi$ is known (given by the user) but $p$ is unknown at the time of planning the experiment.)

Comment: I think I can replace $\dfrac{\pi-\pi_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}}$ by $\dfrac{\pi-\pi_0}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{n}}}$ and argue that $\dfrac{\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{n}}{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}} = 1$ asymptotically. Correct?

Comment: Yes, almost. The sample proportion is (at least under random sampling or similar suitable assumptions) a consistent estimator of $\pi$, ie $p\to_p\pi$ as $n\to\infty$. By the continuous mapping theorem, $p(1-p)\to_p \pi(1-\pi)$. Then, the numerator of what is left of what I have in my comment is $\sqrt{n}(p-\pi)$, which, by the CLT, tends to a $N(0,\pi(1-\pi))$. Then, use Slutzky's theorem to combine the two results to establish that $\sqrt{n}(p-\pi)/\sqrt{p(1-p))}\to_d N(0,1)$.

Comment: By "almost", I mean that what you argue to be equal to 1 asymptotically will actually converge to $0/0$, as both numerators in the ratio are bounded and divided by $n$, $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Also, aren't you looking at the wrong tail of the distribution of the test statistic? As you test against $\pi>\pi_0$, a $p$ such that $p>\pi_0$ or equivalently, a positive test statistic yield evidence against $H_0$.